# start uwsgi writing log before completion of wsgi-file

Tags: python, logging, uwsgi

Can uwsgi logs be written before wsgi-file initialization completes?

My application has a long running initialization in the wsgi-file, and the logs from that initialization are delayed until completion, which complicates debugging (and also would result in zero logs if there were an infinite loop).

For example, I run `rm *.log; uwsgi --ini config.ini` with this `config.ini`:

```
[uwsgi]
http=:9090
logger=file:uwsgi.log
hook-master-start=exec:touch hook_started.log
wsgi-file=foobar.py
```

And this `foobar.py`

```
import logging
import os.path

logging.warn("logging entry")
with open('manual_init.log', 'w') as init_log_file:
    init_log_file.write("init file entry\n")

for expected_file_path in ('manual_init.log', 'hook_started.log', 'uwsgi.log'):
    logging.warn("%s file exists during init? %s" % (expected_file_path, os.path.exists(expected_file_path)))

def application(env, start_response):
    for expected_file_path in ('manual_init.log', 'hook_started.log', 'uwsgi.log'):
        logging.warn("%s file exists during app call? %s" % (expected_file_path, os.path.exists(expected_file_path)))

    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [b"Hello World"]
```

And the uwsgi.log contains these entries:

```
WARNING:root:logging entry
WARNING:root:manual_init.log file exists during init? True
WARNING:root:hook_started.log file exists during init? False
WARNING:root:uwsgi.log file exists during init? False
```

After `curl http://localhost:9090/` I get these additional uwsgi.log entries:

```
WARNING:root:manual_init.log file exists during app call? True
WARNING:root:hook_started.log file exists during app call? True
WARNING:root:uwsgi.log file exists during app call? True
```

Comment: I'm using uwsgi 2.0.13.1, and I also confirmed this occurs on 2.0.15 (the latest stable version)